# An operation can have only one in or out header of a given type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl, wse3.0

Situation: I am trying to consume a clients web service for CC authorization.  They are not publishing the WSDL file on there site, but they have provided the WSDL file.  I am using Visual Studio 2005 and creating a web application that consumes the web service.

The only reference to this error that seems to apply is here: http://followtheheard.blogspot.com/2007/12/consuming-web-services.html.  I installed WSE3.0 and configured my project to use WSE and am calling the WSE version of the web reference and I am still getting this error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is poor interoperability between web services written in Java requiring WSE and Visual Studio 2005.  Upgrading to Visual Studio 2008 allows for easier use of the WSE3.0 toolset.